# Set And get requests headers in java script

Tags: java, javascript, request-headers

I have a java application that authenticate users using Http header (HttpServletRequest.getHeader('html-wg-useruid')), How can i set this header from javascript ?

Comment: Why would js set header?

Comment: @Pilot, if you are performing the requests directly from JavaScript, you may need to configure the HTTP request to be correctly received by the target (e.g. a RESTful endpoint). Otherwise your requests won't fetch the correct/expected results.

Comment: 100% this what i want... how to configure the HTTP request to be correctly received by the target. All what i know is the header variable name in the target is 'html-wg-useruid'. Thx a lot

Comment: @user2068662 Please refer to my answer below as it may address your issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **setRequestHeader** method from `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
var httprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httprequest.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
httprequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
httprequest.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'en-us');
```

To retrieve a specific header from the response when you need them, use the **getResponseHeader** method. To get all of them, use **getAllResponseHeaders**.

```
var contentType = httprequest.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
var responseHeaders = httprequest.getAllResponseHeaders();
```

A full list of the available methods can be found in [MDN's XMLHttpRequest page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Methods). Take a look at it if you are interested.

Comment: Ok lets say that i set my variable: httprequest.setRequestHeader('html-wg-useruid', 'gptadmin2'); How now to submit this change and check if the target application read this variable

Comment: The change will be automatically reflected in your `httprequest` object. To submit it call the `send()` method in the request.
To check that the target application read the variable you need to receive the expected result. You can debug the application in server side if you have access to it.